# UnifiedPush Server: Request to remove an installation from Node.js backend

Tags: aerogear

Can I send a request to remove a particular installation (device) from my backend Node.js server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you could do it, here are the modules:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/unifiedpush-admin-client

This implements the endpoint here: https://aerogear.org/docs/specs/aerogear-unifiedpush-rest/#-2081373521

OR

https://www.npmjs.com/package/unifiedpush-registration-client

This implenents the endpoint here: https://aerogear.org/docs/specs/aerogear-unifiedpush-rest/#417932897

The second option probably has slightly less config